# Server Error in '/' Application MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to add a new view for my website however I keep on getting the error Server Error in '/' Application. My view is linked to the controller and my route config file has the right the path. Any help would be grateful.

Profile controller

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Bitev2.Controllers
    {
        public class ProfileController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Profile/
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            //
            // GET: /Profile/Details/5
            public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                return View();
            }

            //
            // GET: /Profile/Create
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }

            //
            // POST: /Profile/Create
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO: Add insert logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

            //
            // GET: /Profile/Edit/5
            public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                return View();
            }

            //
            // POST: /Profile/Edit/5
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO: Add update logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }

            //
            // GET: /Profile/Delete/5
            public ActionResult Delete(int id)
            {
                return View();
            }

            //
            // POST: /Profile/Delete/5
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // TODO: Add delete logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Profile view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile";
}

<h2>Profile</h2>
```

Route config file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Bitev2
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: For which URL, you are getting this error? Can you share that URL?

Comment: Do you have a home controller?

Comment: I thought, you have to enter id at runtime or which authentication you are using. check in web.config file.

Comment: Yes I have a home controller the url that I'm getting the error with is  http://localhost:53954/Profile/Profile

Comment: @user3229621 you dont have a "Profile" action method in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present only following URLs are permitted by your controller structure -

```
/profile/index
/profile/details/id
/profile/create
/profile/edit/id
/profile/delete/id
```

Post Operations supported URLs -

```
/profile/create
/profile/edit/id
/profile/delete/id
```

And you are trying `/profile/profile` and it does not exist. so that is the reason why you are getting error. Either create profile action or try to handle 404 errors using [Custom Errors section](http://www.secretgeek.net/custom_errors_mvc.asp).

Answer (score 1):

With these defaults it should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Profile", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    });
```

**controller = "Profile"**